# How to concat or merge two or more video files in Android?

Tags: java, android, video

I want to merge two or more video files (they may be two mp4 or two 3gp, or any other format).

Comment: ffmpeg is a great library dealing with video conversions and what not. There is a java binding located here: http://code.google.com/p/jjmpeg/

Comment: I have used FileInputSream to get srouce files and then SequenceInputStream(stream1,stream2) to combine two files, but it think this not proper way work with video files , also android fall around issue of memory leak if heap size extends more than 16MB

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The most generic tool you can use is ffmpeg (as noted by @Jeremy above), but using it on the mobile handset will require some work; also it is LGPL licensed and some of its encoders (notably x264) are GPL.

A simpler solution, if both files you want to concatenate are using similar encoding, and are contained in file formats derived from MP4 (3GP is such), is to use a pure-java MP4 parser and concatenate the videos without touching the media stream itself. Have a look at [mp4parser](https://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/), an open-source parser that is pure-java, licensed under Apache license and even has an [example for concatenating videos](https://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/wiki/AppendTracks) in its wiki.

Comment: cool , the mp4 parser works for the 2 files , but it's not working properly for more than 2 files, video is not merge properly. is it work for more than 2 files simultaneously?

Comment: @Mahesh merge two files, then merged the merged file with the next and so on?

Comment: @Cheesebaron Is this possible what u are telling ?

Answer (score 5):

You can try INDE Media for Mobile, tutorials are here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inde-media-pack-for-android-tutorials

It has transcoding\remuxing functionality in MediaComposer class and a possibility to join file\file segments. Since it uses MediaCodec API inside encoding is done on GPU so is very battery friendly and works as fast as possible.

Sample code showing how to enable join or other functionality is on github: https://github.com/INDExOS/media-for-mobile

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

**I will share both Java & Kotlin Code**

Internally it uses FFmpeg but its lightweight.The easiest way to Add two videos of different types or codec, framerate, and bitrate is to use EpMedia librabry.

**Grade Dependency**

```
implementation 'com.github.yangjie10930:EpMedia:v0.9.5'
```

**Kotlin Code**

```
    val epVideos = ArrayList<EpVideo>()
    epVideos.add(EpVideo("/storage/emulated/0/Contact/1.mp4")) // Video 1 Example
    epVideos.add(EpVideo("/storage/emulated/0/Contact/2.mp4")) // Video 2 Exmaple
    val outputOption = EpEditor.OutputOption ("/storage/emulated/0/merge.mp4"); //Output
    outputOption.setWidth(720) // output video width, default 480
    outputOption.setHeight(1280)
    outputOption.frameRate =  25 ; // output video frame rate, default 30

    EpEditor.merge(epVideos,outputOption,object:OnEditorListener{
        override fun onSuccess() {

        }

        override fun onFailure() {

        }


        override fun onProgress(progress: Float) {
            Log.d("Progress","$progress")
        }

    })
```

**Java Code**

```
 private void mergeVideos() {
    ArrayList<EpVideo> epVideos =  new  ArrayList<>();
    epVideos.add(new EpVideo (file2)); // Video 1
    epVideos.add(new EpVideo (file1)); // Video 2
    EpEditor. OutputOption outputOption =new EpEditor.OutputOption(fileOutput);
    outputOption.setWidth(720);
    outputOption.setHeight(1280);
    outputOption.frameRate = 25 ;
    outputOption.bitRate = 10 ;
    EpEditor.merge(epVideos, outputOption, new  OnEditorListener() {
        @Override
        public  void  onSuccess () {
            Log.d("Status","Success");

        }

        @Override
        public  void  onFailure () {

        }

        @Override
        public  void  onProgress ( float  progress ) {
            // Get processing progress here
            Log.d("Progress",""+progress);
        }
    });

}
```