# Smooth playback of consecutive mp4 video sequences on Android

Tags: android, video, android-mediacodec

I want to play (render to surface) two or more consecutive mp4 video sequences (each stored in a separate file on my device and maybe not present at startup) on my Android device in a smooth (no stalls, flicker, etc.) manner. So, the viewer might get the impression of watching only one continuous video. In a first step it would be sufficient to achieve this only for my Nexus 7 tablet.
For displaying only one video I have been using the *MediaCodec API* in a similar way to http://dpsm.wordpress.com/2012/07/28/android-mediacodec-decoded/ and it works fine. By only creating (and configure) the second decoder after the first sequence has finished (*decoder.stop* and *decoder.release* of the first one was called), one can see the blending. For a smooth fade between two different video sequences I was thinking about having an *init* functionality where the second video is already initialized via *decoder.configure(format, surface, null, 0)* during the playback of the first one. Furthermore the first frame is also queued via *decoder.queueInputBuffer*.
But doing so results to the following error:

```
01-13 16:20:37.182: E/BufferQueue(183): [SurfaceView] connect: already connected (cur=3, req=3)
01-13 16:20:37.182: E/MediaCodec(9148): native_window_api_connect returned an error: Invalid argument (-22)
01-13 16:20:37.182: E/Decoder Init(9148): Exception decoder.configure: java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

It seems to me that one surface can only be used by one decoder simultaneously. So, is there any other possibility for doing that? Maybe using OpenGL?

Best,
Alex.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe with using multiple instances of `MediaCodec` will work, but you can only have one "producer" connected to a Surface at a time.  You'd need to tear down the first before you can proceed with the second, and I'm not sure how close you can get the timing.

What you can do instead is decode to a `SurfaceTexture`, and then draw that on the SurfaceView (using, as you thought, OpenGL).

You can see an example of rendering MP4 files to a `SurfaceTexture` in the [ExtractMpegFramesTest](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#ExtractMpegFramesTest) example.  From there you just need to render the texture to your surface (`SurfaceView`? `TextureView`?), using something like the `STextureRender` class in [CameraToMpegTest](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#CameraToMpegTest).

There's some additional examples in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika/), though the video player there is closer to what you already have (decoder outputs to `TextureView`).

Incidentally, you'll need to figure out how much of a delay to put between the last frame of movie N and the first frame of movie N+1.  If the recordings were taken at fixed frame rates it's easy enough, but some sources (e.g. `screenrecord`) don't record that way.

**Update:** If you can guarantee that your movie clips have the same characteristics (size, encoding type -- essentially everything in `MediaFormat`), there's an easier way.  You can `flush()` the decoder when you hit end-of-stream and just start feeding in the next file.  I use this to loop video in the Grafika video player (see [MoviePlayer#doExtract()](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/MoviePlayer.java)).

Comment: Thanks to your example (ExtractMpegFramesTest) decoding to a SurfaceTexture worked out quit well! Now I am facing the problem of rendering the texture to the surface. To the best of my knowledge CameraToMpegTest is also storing the video without displaying, right? I am fine with SurfaceView as well as TextureView but according to http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/environment.html it might be easier to choose TextureView. 
Ps.: Yes, it is guaranteed that the movie clips have the same characteristics and fixed frame rates.

Comment: The bigflake samples don't display anything.  ExtractMpegFramesTest creates a SurfaceTexture, and directs the MediaCodec output to it.  To display the output on a TextureView, you want to change the code so that it uses the SurfaceTexture from `TextureView#getSurfaceTexture()` instead.  The TextureView class will then take care of latching the buffer and rendering it to the screen.  (If you use a SurfaceView you have to do the rendering yourself.)

Comment: I made some changes according to your advice; I created a TextureView and set a Listener via `mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this)`. I forward the SurfaceTexture to the CodecOutputSurface and use it instead of creating a new one. But when I try to attach it to the GL Context via `mSurfaceTexture.attachToGLContext(mTextureRender.getTextureId())` I am getting the following error: “E/GLConsumer: [unnamed-11969-0] attachToContext: GLConsumer is already attached to a context”. Is it even necessary to attach it? How to proceed from here?

Comment: You don't want to mess with the EGL context of the `SurfaceTexture` you get from `SurfaceView`.  That's owned by the UI thread.  Take a look at `TextureViewGLActivity` in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika).  In `Renderer#run()`, it creates a new EGL context and uses the `TextureView`'s `SurfaceTexture` as the surface.  The trick is that you're not drawing on the `TextureView`'s `EGLSurface`, you're drawing on its `Surface`... those are entirely different things.  You draw on the `Surface` which maps to a texture, and `TextureView` renders that to the `EGLSurface`.

Answer (score 0):

Crazy idea. Try [margin the two videos to one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514317/how-to-concat-or-merge-two-or-more-video-files-in-android). They both on your device, so it shouldn't take to long. And you can implement the fade effect by yourself.

Comment: This would definitely be a promising approach in general, but it might be the case that not all video sequences are already stored on my device when the playback of the first one starts and I have to download them meanwhile. Therefore "concatenate" is not an option for me.

Comment: @A.Wolf how about streaming than?

Comment: Sure, it “feels” similar to streaming, but we do not have a continuous stream of frames. Each video sequence is a composition of frames, say about 2 seconds of video.

Comment: @A.Wolf So don't use MP4. Just play images. Sounds more easy that way

Comment: I was also thinking of extracting frame per frame of the mp4 input files and render them separately. Is there a way to display YUV frames directly to the surface? Converting them would take too much time I believe.