# android code to merge two videos side by side and make it as one video(want only one audio)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Any one can help me! 
I have two videos.
I want to merge as one video(side by side) and i need to display side by side and also i don't want to merge two audio.

I want only one audio.So now i want sample codes or reference for video merging code

Comment: Have you considered controlling the volumes of the videos separately, and having one muted?

Comment: Ya that's good idea.Can you give the sample code to merging part@dbillz

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment so I am writing this as answer.

Muting one video is a good idea as dbilz suggested.

For merging videos use ffmpeg. If both the files you want to concatenate are using similar encoding try [mp4parser](https://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/)

Look this question for more [merging two or more video files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514317/how-to-concat-or-merge-two-or-more-video-files-in-android)

Comment: ThanX for your answer. I will check and let Inform the result

Answer (score 0):

**Gradle Dependency**

```
implementation "com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2"
```

**Code**

*Command to concate two video side by side into one*

```
val cmd : arrayOf("-y", "-i", videoFile!!.path, "-i", videoFileTwo!!.path, "-filter_complex", "hstack", outputFile.path)
```

*Note* :

> "videoFile" is your first video path.
> "videoFileTwo" is your second video path.
> "outputFile" is your combined video path which is our final output path

*To create output path of video*

```
fun createVideoPath(context: Context): File {
        val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat(Constant.DATE_FORMAT, Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
        val imageFileName: String = "APP_NAME_"+ timeStamp + "_"
        val storageDir: File? = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES)
        if (storageDir != null) {
            if (!storageDir.exists()) storageDir.mkdirs()
        }
        return File.createTempFile(imageFileName, Constant.VIDEO_FORMAT, storageDir)
    }
```

*Code to execute command*

```
try {
            FFmpeg.getInstance(context).execute(cmd, object : ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
                override fun onStart() {

                }

                override fun onProgress(message: String?) {
                    callback!!.onProgress(message!!)
                }

                override fun onSuccess(message: String?) {
                    callback!!.onSuccess(outputFile)
                }

                override fun onFailure(message: String?) {
                    if (outputFile.exists()) {
                        outputFile.delete()
                    }
                    callback!!.onFailure(IOException(message))
                }

                override fun onFinish() {
                    callback!!.onFinish()
                }
            })
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            
        } catch (e2: FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException) {
           
        }
```

Comment: Can you get hardware encoding on android with this solution? I looked into this problem a few years ago and ffmpeg didn't have hardware support for mediacodec and encoding. It was dreadfully slow.