# Merging/concat videos in android through FFMPEG

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am working on video merging application through FFMPEG. My code is working if i select two same videos. but if i select two different video with different bit-rate and resolution then video merging is not working.
I am using this commands.

```
List<String> cmdList = new ArrayList<>();
cmdList.add("-y");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < videoList.size(); i++) {
    cmdList.add("-i");
    cmdList.add(videoList.get(i).getThumbnailPath());
    sb.append("[").append(i).append(":0] [").append(i).append(":1]");
}

sb.append(" concat=n=").append(videoList.size()).append(":v=1:a=1 [v] [a]");
cmdList.add("-filter_complex");
cmdList.add(sb.toString());
cmdList.add("-map");
cmdList.add("[v]");
cmdList.add("-map");
cmdList.add("[a]");
cmdList.add("-preset");
cmdList.add("ultrafast");
cmdList.add("storage/emulated/0/abcfs.mp4");

sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String str : cmdList) {
    sb.append(str).append(" ");
}

String[] cmd = cmdList.toArray(new String[cmdList.size()]);
```

I also used this command.

```
String[] complexCommand = {
    "-y", "-i", 
    pathArraylist.get(0),
    "-i", pathArraylist.get(1), 
    "-strict", 
    "experimental", 
    "-filter_complex",
    "[0:v]scale=hd720,setsar=1:1[v0];[1:v]scale=hd720,setsar=1:1[v1];[v0][0:a][v1][1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1",
    "-ab", 
    "48000", 
    "-ac", 
    "2", 
    "-ar", 
    "22050", 
    "-s", 
    "hd720", 
    "-vcodec", 
    "mpeg4", 
    "-b:v", 
    "600" +"k", 
    "storage/emulated/0/outputvideo.mp4"
};
```

Please let me know which command I used if I concatenate two videos with different bit-rate and resolution.

Comment: Check this solution, It worked like a Charm. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60398328/10182932

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to bring both the videos to be concatenated to same resolutions. This can either be done independently first by using ffprobe to determine WxH of videos and scaling one video to the resolution of another video.

This can also be done altogether by:

1. Determine WxH of first video using ffprobe.
2. Concatenating videos using the following:

> ffmpeg -y  -i  input-1.mp4 -i input-2.mp4 -filter_complex
>   "[0:v]setsar=1:1[v0];[1:v]scale=W:H,setsar=1:1[v1];[v0][0:a][v1][1:a]
>   concat=n=2:v=1:a=1" out.mp4

[0:v]setsar=1:1[v0], sets  Sample aspect ratio of 1st video stream to 1:1, it can also be different but similar to the one being used in other input's video stream as in [1:v]scale=W:H,setsar=1:1[v1]. This would scale [1:v] stream to [0:v] video's resolution. You can also modify this command to take care of aspect ratio of 2nd video and by including black stripe paddings which are beyond the scope of this question.

And to take care of bit rates, you can explicitly specify encoder parameters for creating your concatenated video and it should take care of everything as both video's video streams will be re-encoded again. You can use something like:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input-1.mp4 -i input-2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setsar=1:1[v0];
[1:v]scale=W:H,setsar=1:1[v1];[v0][0:a][v1][1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1" -
c:v libx264 -b:v 600K -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128K out.mp4
```

Comment: the second you write will work for the videos with different resolution and bitrate?

Comment: Yes it will, provided the filter_complex is provided with correct parameters, i.e. all the input video streams having same sample aspect ratio, same resolution (which may require scaling in few input videos), and if you specify encoder parameters for output, i.e. video codec, target bitrate, etc.

Comment: show me this Error when i run the command Unknown encoder libfdk_aac

Comment: when i change the encoding to aac then this error shown 
[Parsed_scale_1 @ 0xb77054b0] [Eval @ 0xbeb5ea70] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'W'[Parsed_scale_1 @ 0xb77054b0] [Eval @ 0xbeb5ea70] Undefined constant or missing '(' in'H'
Error when evaluating the expression 'H'.
"Error configuring complex filters. Invalid argument"

Comment: It means that your ffmpeg was not compiled with libfdk_aac encoder library. You can remove audio encoder options and let ffmpeg decide by itself if you are not sure what audio libraries you have on your system. You can use AAC(libfdk_aac), MP3(lame mp3 probably, I am not sure about it) but for that you will have to recompile ffmpeg with required libraries.

Comment: Also you need to replace W and H with actual width and height values of target resolution you want. Specifying W and H won't work, I added it in example for illustration. Replace them with actual values.

Comment: the video merging is very slow it takes alot of time for merging two small videos

Comment: Use preset fast/ultrafast.

Comment: can you please update the answer and let me know how to merge three video using this command thanks.

Comment: Hi, that's beyond the scope of your question. Either update your question or ask a new question. This would help others as well. Comments are not meant for discussing a new question.